# If the probability density function of X is f(x)=sin(x) then what is the variance of X?

Tags: self-study, variance, distributions, integral, probability-calculus

I am studying a random variable X with probability density function

f(x) = sin(x)

the domain of X is (0,pi/2). I'm trying to determine the variance of X. I know

var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2

how do i determine E(X)? do i calculate x*P(X=x) across a grid of values and sum them? I have similar questions about calculating E(X^2). Is it possible to use a simulation based approach to estimating E(X)? I do not need an exact answer.

Comment: Perhaps is there some way I can use the fact that E(X) = integral P(X>x)??? to simplify this calculation? Is so, how do I calculate P(X>x)?

Comment: $E(X)=\int_a^b x f(x) dx$ where $[a,b]$ is the domain and $f(x)$ the density.

Comment: ok but where does X enter the equation? what values to use for a and b?

Comment: $E(X)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x sin(x) dx$ because in your example  $[a,b]=[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is the domain and $f(x)=sin(x)$ the density.

Comment: is it possible to simplfy int(0,pi/2) x*sin(x)? Can I calculate [int(0,pi/2) x]*[int(0,pi/2) sin(x)]?

Comment: You can't do like that, I would try partial integration.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_integration_(contract_law)  I don't understand

Comment: $P(X>a)=\int_{a}^{\pi/2} sin(x)dx$.  Avoid the notation $P(X>x)$, since this leads to ambiguity in the notation- is $x$ the lower bound of the integral or the variable of integration?

Comment: You really don't want the calculus to get in the way of understanding the probability theory here.  Can you setup integrals for $E[X]$ and $E[X^{2}]$ and then evaluate the integrals using a symbolic computation tool like Wolfram Alpha?  Once you've got an answer then you can go back and do a bit of calculus review to figure out how to evaluate the integrals by hand.

Comment: Try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: I know how to integrate x and how to integrate sin(x). Can I use that information to calculate E(X) and E(X^2)?

Comment: fcop, which one is u and which one is v in my case? do I have to solve for them? but, doesn't that require me to know beforehand what the integral is? from xi'an's post I think the answer is 1/7. Can I enter that value?

Comment: Do you know how to integrate $x\sin(x)$ and $x^2\sin(x)$?

Comment: I think the tip from @Xi'an here is: $var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]^2 = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2}x^2sin(x)dx-\left[ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}xsin(x)dx\right]^2= (\pi - 2) - (1)^2 = \pi - 3$.

Answer (score 4):

Simulating from the density $$f(x)=\sin(x)\mathbb{I}_{(0,\pi/2)}(x)$$ can be done by the inverse cdf method, since the cdf is then
$$F(x)=\int_0^x \sin(x)\text{d}x=1-\cos(x)\qquad 0\le x\le\pi/2$$
The inverse cdf method consists in simulating $U\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$, a standard Uniform, and then solving $F(x)=u$, which in this case means
$$1-\cos(x)=u\quad\text{i.e.}\quad x=\arccos(1-u)$$

The Monte Carlo approximations to mean and variance are then easily coded, for instance in R

```
>mean(acos(runif(1e5)))
[1] 1.000211

>var(acos(runif(1e5)))
[1] 0.1415383
```

Note that the expectation coincides with your suggestion to use the identity$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^{\pi/2} \{1-F(x)\}\,\text{d}x=\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x)\,\text{d}x=1$$

Comment: Does this mean the variance of X is roughly 1/7?

Comment: Can I bother you with a math background question? How does the $\mathbb{I}$ work?

Comment: linksys, the variance of $X$ is *exactly* $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos(x) \mathrm{d}(x^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2 = \pi - 3$, which indeed is close to $1/7$.

Comment: @AntoniParellada its an identity function where only equals 1 on the range provided.